# Underscorejs changes function to object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

**Edit:** I realized I passed `MyConstructorFunc.prototype` to `_.extend().

I ran into an interesting implementation detail when I wanted to extend a function with Underscore.

I built a function constructor,

```
var MyConstructorFunc = function() {
  ...
}
```

then I returned the result of

```
return _.extend(MyConstructorFunc.prototype, {
  \\ ...some properties...
}
```

What I got back was a `typeof MyConstructorFunc == "object"`! If `_.extend` is merging properties into a `function` why does it return an `object`?

Looking at the `_.extend` function I don't see where that happens...

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
    if (!_.isObject(obj)) return obj;
    var source, prop;
    for (var i = 1, length = arguments.length; i < length; i++) {
      source = arguments[i];
      for (prop in source) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(source, prop)) {
            obj[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
  };
```

If I do `MyConstructorFunc["someProp"] = someObject["someProp"]` and `return MyConstructorFunc`, I returned a JavaScript `object`?

I'm missing something...

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this error. Can you post the content of `MyConstructorFunc` function and the object you're passing to the `_.extend` function.

Comment: The result of  `_.isFunction(_.extend(MyConstructorFunc , { ...}))` returned `true` for you?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably passing in a Function object to _.extend. Your sample code does not show it, but if you are making a new instance of your MyConstructorFunc using the "new" keyword, then the result will be an object.

```
var MyConstructorFunc = function() {
}

var foo = _.extend(MyConstructorFunc, {a:1});
console.log(typeof foo); // function 

var funcObj = new MyConstructorFunc();
console.log(typeof funcObj); //object
```

Extending the MyConstructorFunc itself will return a function type. It's once you use the contructor to create a new function that you are given an object.

Comment: Thanks @BrianTovar I forgot to add an important detail. Please see revised code.